# Compilation error "type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace" - simple MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Created "helloworld" project with **MVC 5** in **VS 2013 Ult**. After hit **Start** button get following error in IE:

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**ASP.Net** version is **4.5.1**
**System.Web.Mvc** is in **References** with **Version 5.0.0.0** (Runtime version v4.0.30319)

Here's a part of **web.config**:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc,    Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="mvc2" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Tried to update **asp.net mvc package**:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.5.1
No updates available for 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
```

What else could I try?

Comment: Can you set `Copy Local = True` for System.Web.Mvc Reference and give it a try?

Comment: Thanks! Now it's ok! Changed Copy local to True in in System.Web.Mvc properties in Solution explorer

Comment: Can I post my comment as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `Copy Local = True` for System.Web.Mvc Reference in Solution Explorer (by selecting the reference and clicking F4).